# How the rewrite in clean url structure with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have change the structure of my website: removed the /nl/ folder and switch the underscores to a stripe.
So the wish is to redirect the old page:
www.example.com/nl/citygames_leuven 
to
http://www.example.com/citygames-leuven

The redirects works for a bit; but gets in problem with my clean URL redirection.
I got redirected to:
http://www.example.com/citygames-leuven?url=nl/citygames_leuven

As you see; the url parameter sticks in and gives error on the page.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Options All -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 


RewriteRule ^teambuilding/(.*)/?$ teambuilding.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^citygame/(.*)/?$ citygame.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^meeting/(.*)/?$ meeting.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^aanzee/(.*)/?$ aanzee.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^vip/(.*)/?$ vip.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^verhuur/(.*)/?$ verhuur.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^nieuws/(.*)/?$ nieuws.php?url=$1 [L]


#Url omzetten naar index.php?page= 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ page.php?url=$1 [QSA] 



Redirect 301 /nl/citygames_antwerpen http://www.example.com/citygames-antwerpen
Redirect 301 /nl/citygames_leuven http://www.example.com/citygames-leuven
Redirect 301 /nl/teambuilding/offroad_buggy http://www.example.com/teambuilding/offroad-buggy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorder your rules and place 301 before internal rewrite rules:

```
Options All -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^nl/citygames_antwerpen/?$ /citygames-antwerpen [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^nl/citygames_leuven/?$ /citygames-leuven [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^nl/teambuilding/offroad_buggy/?$ /teambuilding/offroad-buggy [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^teambuilding/(.*)/?$ teambuilding.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^citygame/(.*)/?$ citygame.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^meeting/(.*)/?$ meeting.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^aanzee/(.*)/?$ aanzee.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^vip/(.*)/?$ vip.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^verhuur/(.*)/?$ verhuur.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^nieuws/(.*)/?$ nieuws.php?url=$1 [L]

#Url omzetten naar index.php?page= 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ page.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

PS: Also better to do this in `mod_rewrite` itself and avoid `mod_alias` rules.